# Preserve specific files from auto-update using electron-builder

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, electron, electron-builder

I have an **Electron** application where I saved information into a `JSON` file. But this is unique for every user and I am not able to store it online. I want to preserve this file when I am deploying a new version of the application and I do not want it to be removed.

Is there a way to lock a folder for not being replaced in `electron-builder` ?

Maybe I can store them into an OS path into the user's machine but I am not certain I can trust the user to not delete them unpurposely.

Comment: See: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname